# android - hide point inside Image onTouch Event

Tags: android, imageview, touch-event

I Have Imageview with Image in my Android app. I want that the point on the image that user touched on will disappear.

any Ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an OnTouchListener to that View, and when touched get the coordinates and redraw the View and draw over it on the canvas the pixel you want, i.e. a white pixel, to the position you want.

This is pretty much the flow..

Hope this helps!

Comment: But the main idea is to show other image that located behind that image. what is the right way to do it?